# hidden images when scroll uitableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, grand-central-dispatch

I am doing this code

but when i scroll the uitableview image will disappear what i want i want when image once load then it will not disapper.

Please tell me what can i do in this.

```
__block NSData *image = nil;
dispatch_queue_t imageQueue = dispatch_queue_create("queueForCellImage", NULL);
dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^{
    NSString *thumbnailURL = @"http://www.bizfy.com/demo/biscoot/a1.png";
    image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailURL]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:image];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    });
});
dispatch_release(imageQueue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the images in an NSArray, NSDictionary or even in the file system. Instead of only setting `cell.imageView`, try to store in a NSMutableArray or save to the disk, and in the next time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, you access the image where you stored it.

Some code with the NSMutableDictionary solution, assuming you are using ARC (try to understand):

In your interface file, you declare a `NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryImages;`

In your implementation file, initiate it in `viewDidLoad` method: `dictionaryImages = [NSMutableDictionaryImages dictionary];`

Now, where you download your images, you also should insert the image in your dictionary (I'm not posting all your code, just the relevant parts from that piece)

```
NSString *thumbnailURL = @"http://www.bizfy.com/demo/biscoot/a1.png";
UIImage *imageForDictionary = [UIImage imageWithData:image];
[dictionaryImages setObject:imageForDictionary forKey:thumbnailURL];
```

And then, when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, you associate it to the image (of course, if you have access to the thumbnailURL):

```
NSString *thumbnailURL = **get it from somewhere**;
UIImage *imageFromDictionary = [dictionaryImages objectForKey:thumbnailURL];
cell.imageView.image = imageFromDictionary;
```

Comment: Thanks Natan, can you pls give me a link or any code because i dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than holding previously downloaded images in `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray`, I'd suggest using [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/index.html). It provides a similar interface as `NSMutableDictionary` (e.g. has a `setObject:forKey:` method), but you can also configure how many images should be cached (via the `countLimit` or other mechanisms). You might also want to add an observer for `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` to empty the cache upon memory pressure.

If you want to take it to the next level, when downloading images used in `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`, I'd suggest making sure you (a) prioritize visible images over images that may have scrolled off screen; (b) make sure you constrain the degree of concurrency to avoid timeout problems that can plague GCD global queues, etc. The simplest way to achieve that (as well as the `NSCache` behavior) is to use one of the established asynchronous image retrieval `UIImageView` categories, such as those included in [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) (or implement your own variation of the idea).